# Proof of an inequality using Jensen's inequality

Tags: inequality

I want to prove the following inequality.

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\ln(1+\exp(\ln(x)))\right] \geq \ln(1+\exp(\mathbb{E}[\ln(x)])),$$
where $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ is the expectation operator and $x$ is a positive random variable.

I am stuck at the first step, where $\ln(\cdot)$ is a concave function, and thus the inequality sign should be other way according to Jensen's inequality.

Comment: $\log(1+e^t)$ is convex and you can treat $\log X$ as a separate r.v.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!